# Use webworker in the angular 4 app

Tags: angular

I want to know whether there is the way to compile web worker to work with in the angular-cli? 
Or only use the `ng eject` and then configure webpack?

Answer (score 0):

You can compile part of your code (cpu intensive) to run in web worker without using eject.

Here is a presentation that talks about it in details:https://www.slideshare.net/SureshPatidar2/web-worker-in-your-angular-application

Sample code for presentation is available at:

Angular 5:-https://github.com/patidar-suresh/angular5-webworker

Angular 6:- https://github.com/patidar-suresh/angular6-webworker